# Javascript LocalStorage Scope

Tags: javascript, html, scope, local-storage

I am working with localstorage for the first time and have ran into some scope issues.

When I attempt to `console.log(test)` I get `undefined` in my second `if` statement. What am I doing wrong?

My code is as follows;

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    var is_stopped = false;

    source.onmessage = function(event) {

        if (is_stopped) {
            localStorage.setItem('offline', event.data);
            var test = localStorage.getItem('offline');
            console.log(test); // works here
        }       

        if (!is_stopped) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Data:" + event.data + "<br>";
            console.log(test); // undefined 
        }

        $("#start").click(function(){
            is_stopped = false;
        });

        $("#stop").click(function(){
            is_stopped = true;
        });

});

<div id="result"></div>
<button id="stop"> stop</button>
<button id="start"> start</button>
```

Comment: Of course it's undefined. Because you didn't define it. You can't get into both `if (is_stopped)` and `if (!is_stopped)` at the same time.

Comment: Because it is only defined in the `if (is_stopped)` block, and it has no value anywhere else anywhere else, especially in the `if (!is_stopped)` block.

Comment: Where is your click handler? You are setting is_stopped on click, but you are not requesting any further action. You need a handler to tell the browser what you actually want to do after setting the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because *is_stopped* is false, therefore it doesnt enter the first if and doesnt  retrieves the value. Note that variables that are declared inside a function are garbage collected when the function ends.

```
var test;//stays persistent
source.onmessage = function(event) {

    if (is_stopped) {
        localStorage.setItem('offline', event.data);
        test = localStorage.getItem('offline');
        console.log(test); // works here
    }       

    if (!is_stopped) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Data:" + event.data + "<br>";
        console.log(test);
    }
};
```

Hint: moving the click event listeners outside of the other listener makes them work much better...

Answer (score 0):

The variable named `test` is undefined when `is_stopped` is false since it is not declared outside the `is_stoppped` conditional.

This would work:

```
var test = null; // declare outside conditional

if (is_stopped) {
    test = localStorage.getItem('test');
}       

if (!is_stopped) {
    console.log(test); // returns null
}
```

Comment: No, js has function scoping

Comment: @Jonasw Yes... so what's your point? Place this code within the `onmessage` handler and it will behave as described in the comments.

Comment: it *is* declared outside of the conditional

Answer (score 0):

When you run the application `var is_stopped` will be set to false.

In this case `if (!is_stopped) {..}` will be executed.`if (is_stopped) {..}` will not be executed

Due to hosting `var test` will be hoisted to the top of the function & there it is undefined.

`test` will be assigned with a value only if `if (is_stopped) {..}` is executed